# Как создать оконную программу, реализующую связь компьютер-компьютер с общим интерфейсом (JAVA)?

Tags: java, многопоточность, swing, gui

Хочу написать программу на *Java* для двух пользователей.

1. Как создать соединение сервер-клиент (в глобальной сети)?
2. Как создать в общем случае один и тот же интерфейс для двух подконнетившихся пользователей? (пример: любые игры на двоих (крестики-нолики)

Покидайте литературу или статьи в интернете, чтобы прочитать и понять. Читал Хорстмана, "Изучаем Java"...там про локальную сеть описан процесс.

Comment: Клиент-серверное подключение по протоколу TCP/IP не зависит от того где находится сервер на соседнем столе или в соседнем полушарии

Answer (score 0):

Что касается соединения клиент-сервер, то тут есть проблемы. Так как большинство использует динамические ip, то вы просто так не сможете подключиться к какому-то другому клиенту. Поэтому вам стоит использовать что-то вроде master-server'a.

**Как работает мастер-сервер?**

Вы подключаетесь к мастер-серверу, у которого есть статический публичный ip. После чего он записывает вас в список подключенных клиентов. Когда кто-то другой пытается подключиться к вам, он спрашивает у сервера ваш ip и подключается к вам напрямую.

Так же здесь есть еще тонкости. Если вы находитесь за **nat** или **carrier-grade nat** (например byfly - белорусский провайдер - сдедал carrier-grade nat, и теперь по сути ваш ip не виден из сети, даже если вы не находитесь за локальным nat).

**Как пройти через nat?**

Способ есть. Называется он **hole punching**. Суть в кратце: вы подключаетесь к мастер-серверу, обмениваетесь с ним сообщениями. На маршрутизаторах в сети остаются **временные** записи о портах и соответствующих им адресах за nat. Второй клиент делает то же самое, а потом один из них подключается к другому по адресу, который сообщает сервер, "на горячую", т.е. быстро, чтобы записи на маршрутизаторах не потерлись.

Насчет второго вопроса - немного не понял суть